# Redirecting C++ streams

Tags: c++, stream, redirect

I have a method search that I want to feed an input stream and then put output on an output stream.

```
void search(std::istream & is, std::ostream & os);
```

For now I'd like to do this with cin/cout.  From the command prompt:

```
a.out < input_file.txt
```

In main, I try to do this by passing cin/cout to the search() method.

```
X.search(std::cin, std::cout);
```

I get the following error when I compile and link (XCode):

```
Line Location Tool:0: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Line Location Tool:0: symbol(s) not found
Line Location Tool:0: _main in main.o
Line Location Tool:0: "X::search(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&,
   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
```

Is there anything different I need to be doing for cin/cout?  I cannot figure out how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles and runs  fine for me in xcode (c++ cmdline new project wizard), looks like you're missing an #include <iostream> or main, or a definition of your X class.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( std::istream &is, std::ostream &os )
{
    std::string s;
    while ( getline( is, s, '\n' ) )
    {
        os << s;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    foo( std::cin, std::cout );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it at the global scope like you suggested and it worked.  I turned out to be a sloppy error.  I did not include the namespace resolution "X::" when I implemented the method.  I should have caught that!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe your problem is related to std::cin / std::cout.

It's hard to guess from the information given, but I think the problem is that the definition of the search function is not being compiled/linked into your executable.  Is there any more compiler output you can include?

Comment: Unfortunately that is all of the information I have from XCode.  I get almost the same from g++ on the command line, the only difference is that "_main from ccyghqBz.o" is listed as the from point.